# How to create a column in a document folder, that automatically displays the direct online link to the document/image?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, hyperlink, image

I have a SharePoint document folder with 160 images. I would like a column in the folder, that displays the direct hyperlink of each image *automatically*. 'Direct' means that I want the link to display the filename in the end.

For example: `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/foldername/imagefilename.jpg`

I need this to export the image names and the links to a spreadsheet, that will then be used for a database update.

I know that I can create an image archive-folder, add a column for a direct link and then manually copy the path/link from the detail-screen of each photo to the cell in the direct-link-column, but this has to be done manually and one by one. I need the direct link to display automatically.

Warm thanks in advance for anyone who will try to help.

Comment: will you be using SharePoint default "Export to excel" functionality or any custom functionality?

Comment: yes, I will use export to excel